# Squid Proxy on Windows fail to start

Tags: proxy, squid, windows-8

I have a squid proxy running fine on windows , but when I introduce the line

```
url_rewrite_program C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Squid\scripts\1.py
```

Then squid will fail to start with

```
System error 1067 has occurred
```

Anyone had the same issue before , is this option compatible with some specific mode of running squid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error indicates "The process terminated unexpectedly". I'd imagine that Squid is failing to start properly and choking on your configuration file. If you attempt to start Squid from a command prompt (versus starting the service) you'll get some more verbose output about the error.

If memory serves you will need to specify the `url_rewrite_program` with the syntax:

```
url_rewrite_program C:\\Python27\\python.exe C:\\Squid\\scripts\\1.py
```

This will escape the slashes, which is what I expect Squid is choking on.

Comment: Alternatively, use forward slashes instead (/).

Comment: can you point me to some script examples for url_rewrite_program ?